# Controlling which form will load when in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have made a project with Multiple forms in it. I am very beginner and I made main form before the login form.
Now, the main form loads first.
I want the Login form to load first.
What should I do?

EDIT:
When I tried to Change the

```
 static void Main()
    {

        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

To

```
 static void Main()
    {

        Application.Run(new startform());
    }
```

[Image of code after changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebUxp.png) 
When I debugged the application I got I List of Warnings And Errors
[Image of Errors and Warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFhBp.png)

Comment: NO,When I tried to Change the (new myform) to (new otherform) I got a List of errors and warnings.@HamidRezaMohammadi

Comment: Please edit your question. Add some code and errors that you get when change the startup form.

Comment: @HamidRezaMohammadi Done please check now

Comment: An instance of your program seems to be running. Close it first and then run your project.

Comment: @ShreeramGharote: It is true. Your program seems to be running when you try to build(or debug). If you have closed your program and still get this error, then open task manager and find the name of your program in the list and click end task button.Then try to build(or debug) again.

Comment: @DJ It worked Thankyou

Comment: @HamidRezaMohammadi Thankyou

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your program seems to be running when you try to build(or debug).

If you have closed your program and still get this error, then open task manager and find the name of your program in the list and click end task button.

Then try to build(or debug) again.

To prevent this in future, remember to close all your threads, connections and timers once their work is done.

If you don't know about all this specifically, just add the below line to the FormClosed Event of your form:

`Environment.Exit(Environment.ExitCode);`

This specifically ends your code, which automatically stops all threads and timers.

Comment: @ShreeramGharote: Pls read this answer and mark it as the answer. Dont forget to upvote!!:)

Comment: Pls comment the reason to downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Program.cs File and change Name of Form in this line
 Application.Run(**new Form1()**);

Comment: This did not fix my problem. WHen I tried to do this I got a List of errors ad warning while debugging @Muhammad